# ui grid dropdown load from 1 dimensional string array having dynamic data

Tags: angularjs, ui-grid

I am having an ui-grid, one of its column having dropdown, which should be loaded from a string array like $scope.DepotNames = {'abc', 'xyz','uvw'}. These values comes from DB. All the example I have seen online used 2-d array(id and value) to load drop down. How we can use 1 dimensional array to load dropdown values in grid. I don't want to convert my data explicitly to 2-dimension.

Below is the code I found most of the place where data is in 2-dimension array

{

```
  name: 'gender',
  displayName: 'Gender',
  editableCellTemplate: 'ui-grid/dropdownEditor',
  width: '20%',
  cellFilter: 'mapGender',
  editDropdownValueLabel: 'gender',
  editDropdownOptionsArray: [{
    id: 'male',
    gender: 'Male'
  }, {
    id: 'female',
    gender: 'Female'
  }]
```

But I have 1-d Array something like

{

```
  name: 'gender',
  displayName: 'Gender',
  editableCellTemplate: 'ui-grid/dropdownEditor', 
  width: '20%',
  cellFilter: 'mapGender',
  editDropdownValueLabel: 'gender',
  editDropdownOptionsArray: [{'Male','Female'}]
```

}

Comment: post some code..

Comment: Added code above for more details